# Cocoa File Opened Event - Detect if a file was opened

Tags: macos, cocoa, fsevents

I want to ask if it is possible to detect if a file was opened in Finder. I watched at the `File System Events API` and it seems not possible to listen to such an event.

Anyone knows if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with [DTrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html) so it should be possible (with likely a great deal of work) from the high level of your Cocoa app (but your question is too broad to answer without writing such an app for you). Unfortunately no convenient API exists to do what you request.